# how to create xps document on the fly?

Tags: c#, .net, xps

is there any library about this inside the .net framework? or any other open source?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create an XPS document?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/352540/how-to-create-an-xps-document)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the XPSDocument class in .NET to do this. Here is the documentation to the call to [write a Visual to an XPSDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms604601.aspx)